# Agglomerative Clustering with custom distance metric (alternative to the input correlation metric)

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn, correlation, hierarchical-clustering

I'm looking to implement a hierarchical clustering model for my set of training variables with respect to their correlation matrix (it's a 100x100 matrix, and I want the largest cluster whose elements are the most uncorrelated).  I've been able to use the scipy family of functions to do this, however, for visualization and presentations sake, I'd like an alternative correlation distance defined for my data.

The inbuilt distance 'correlation' metric is defined to be 1-r, where r is the pearson score between two variables.  I'd like to change it to 1-absvalue(r)-as my most interesting variables are the most uncorrelated ones (so say the variables who find themselves 1-.8 distance apart).  Thanks!

Comment: Pearson score is calculated between two list of values, not two variables. I don't understand how you want to score them ? Can you please explain a bit in detail.

Comment: Sorry about that, my feature variables [x_1,x_2,_x,3....x_100]are the column entries, and my rows are distinct observations numbering 100,000 trials.  So my original data matrix is about 10,000x100.  

Now, I have my correlation matrix C, which is table of pearson scores for x_i and x_j for integers i and j in  [0,100].  I'd like to implement a divisive (or agglo) hierarchical clustering based on the "correlative distance" between two variables, 1-r, where r is their pearson score.  Ideally, i want to construct clusters whose members are very far apart (so near to 1 in this case)

Thanks!